# Can't add class to Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I tried to add a simple HTML class to my `link_to` tag:

`<%= link_to "Individual Images", action: 'feature_highlights', site_title: site.title, class: "btn"  %>`

..but it gets appended to the URL instead:

How do I add a class to my link_to tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the API docs:

> Be careful when using the older argument style, as an extra literal
>   hash is needed

So, the solution was

`<%= link_to "Individual Images", { action: 'feature_highlights', site_title: site.title }, class: "btn"  %>`